# C DLL for custom project

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I create empty c++ project(VS-2010) that contain c file & header:

[image]

I change the sub system of this project to console.

then I compile and run it.

Now I want to use the dll of this project on C# (I know how to do it, it's not my question)!!

where I found the dll? (or I didn't create it????)

On the debug folder I found the follow files:

[image]

Comment: Application Settings page -> Application type, select DLL

Comment: Er, why did you make a console app?

Comment: @AlexK. How I get the application setting page on c++ empty project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't create a .dll, but a .obj file. So you should be able to include board.obj.

To clarify, the board.obj file contains object code, which is partially compiled code. Visual Studio is able to link against object code since Visual Studio 2005 ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/w63ck4sd.aspx)).